# Delete object's variable after instantiation

Tags: java, object-construction

So I have an object which needs certain variables to be instantiated. These variables are passed to the object through an array of objects. Then, each element in the array gets assigned to an internal variable.

Does this array get garbage collected after the internal variables are assigned and the array is never referenced again, or should it be manually done?

```
class MyObject () {
    public static Object [] values;
    public void setvalues(inputArray) {
        values = inputArray;
    }
}
```

Memory is kind of important because I need to create a few hundred of these objects plus the rest of the code.

Comment: Memory is not important when talking about a few hundred objects. You worry about memory when each object would require several megabyte; or when you have many many millions of objects. Unless you are on such a scale (and you ran into real problems) ... questions as this indicate that you do not understand what Java memory problems are really about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether the array is eligible for GC depends on this condition:

- Is there anything still referencing the array?

If, you have something like this:

```
public class Foo {
    private int[] myArray = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    YourObject obj;

    public void someMethod() {
        obj = new YourObject(myArray);
    }
}
```

Then `myArray` is not eligible for garbage collection because the variable `myArray` in the `Foo` object is still referencing it. You can then set `myArray` to `null` to make it eligible for GC.

If `myArray` were a local variable, however:

```
public class Foo {
    YourObject obj;
    public void someMethod() {
        int[] myArray = {1, 2, 3, 4};
        obj = new YourObject(myArray);
    }
}
```

Then it is eligible for GC after `someMethod` returns because `myArray` will have gone out of scope by then.

Also, note that "eligible for GC" doesn't mean "will be collected immediately". It just mean that the GC has a possibility of collecting it in the future. When exactly? We don't know.

Comment: And in general, we don't care when. If those value should really need to be erased, I would fill the array with `0` after usage. (same way we use `char[]` for password)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your code looks like this

```
//Client class
o.setValues(arrayOfObjects);
//In the receiving object
public void setValues (Object[] objects){
 // Dostuff
}
```

Two things need to happen for `arrayOfObjects` to be a candidate for GC -

1. `arrayOfObjects` needs to go out of scope. OR
2. arrayOfObject needs to be assigned another value or `null`.

If you are *really* concerned about memory, I would surmise it's the contents of the array that need to be garbage collected, not the array itself. The contents will clearly be referenced by the receiving object, so they will not be garbage collected.
Hope this helps.